# Why does my axios call return undefined even after then is resolved?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm currently using functions to predefine all of my axios calls so for example:

```
export const getClients = () => {
    axios.get("/client/")
        .then(response=>{
            return response;
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            return error;
        });
    };
```

Now, I want to call this in a class-based component in the `componentDidMount` like this:

```
  componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({
            clients: getClients()
        });
  }
```

I can't seem to figure out why when I try to `console.log(this.state.clients)` at the end of `componentDidMount` I'm getting an undefined error. I'm new to React and from what I understand, the `then` in the function of the axios call should resolve the promise and return the actual response from the API call so when I call `getClients()`, the `clients` state should be the response.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `getClients()` it's a promise, you need to `await` plus retun inside `getClients`

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, it should be `export const getClients = async ()....` or something else?

Comment: use await where you are calling it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay there is some stuff that needs to be cleared out here :-

1. You need to change `getClients` like so :-

```
export const getClients = () => {
    return axios.get("/client/")
        .then(response=>{
            return response;
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            return error;
        });
    };
```

Why ?
Because the value that you returned from the callback of `then` is wrapped inside a Promise implicitly and has to be returned for consumption as you do in a function like `function sum(a,b) {return a+b}`

2. `componentDidMount` will change like so :-

```
componentDidMount(){
       const fetchClients = async () => {
            const clients = await getClients();
             this.setState({clients});
         }
       fetchClients();    
  }
```

Why ?
If you want to use `getClients` in a statement fashion instead of `.then().then()` promise chain, you will first wrap it inside an `async` function and then call `await` on `getClients()` (remember this function returns a `Promise`) and then set the state inside that async function.

3. Even if you `console.log` the `clients` state after `fetchClients()` within `componentDidMount`, you probably won't see the value set because `setState` works asynchronously. So never rely on the `console.log` of your state just after setting it.

Comment: Thank you but I'm now getting `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`.

Comment: Updated fetchClients from regular function to arrow function. Now try.

Comment: It now works. Just one more questions, why did it work now with an arrow function and not with a regular one seeing as they were both async? 

And also, can the `await getClients()` be changed to something with `.then(..)` ?

Comment: Arrow functions take the "this" value from their lexical outer scope and in outer scope the value of "this" is the Class component instance itself. Regular functions don't work that way. I would encourage you to read more about them. A lot of stuff goes behind the scenes. Yes await getClients() can be changed to getClients().then(res=>setState.....). In that case you don't need that wrapper async function.

Answer (score 1):

```
 componentDidMount(){
       fetchClients();    
  }

  const fetchClients = () => {
    getClients().then( (response)=> {
      // handle success
             this.setState({clients:response});

    });
  };
```